# a strange question of x86 address translation, when the page table not correct

Tags: linux, x86, operating-system

I'm doing some work about os kernel and i find a very strange problem.
I move the part of process's page table to userspace, just the pud level, and the pgd level still in kernel space. The new pud entry is not correct. So when i run the process, there will be a page fault for a user space virtual address and the os reboot.

Through the crash tool, I find the content of the cr2 register is 0xffff8800d1802050. My log show the new pud entry is 0xd1802067. I think the address translation is completed by hardware, so the pgd is physical, pud is physical. when the pud is not correct, why the cr2 is a virtual address? is there some implict rule?

Comment: @harold yes, cr2 is PFLA, the meaning of my question is that, if the pud is not correct, in the process of the address translation, mmu use the physical addr to access each level of page table(except cr3), so why cr2 is the kernel linear addresss?

Comment: @MichaelPetch yes, cr3 is physical address, cr2 is linear address. In the process of address translation, is it complete by hardware automatic? through the pgd entry, the hardware will to access the pud page, but the entry is error, why the content of cr2 is set to a linear address? how does this linear address compute? In 64bit linux, the content is the kernel linear address, is the hardware will add the physical address with the kernel start address automatic?

Comment: Do you have a github/gitlab project (or your code online somewhere)so I can look at it?

Comment: "I move the part of process's page table to userspace" - does that not seem a little ... dangerous? :-)

Comment: I don't understand the question. `CR2` is set to the LA that caused the fault, as-soon-as the CPU detects a PF. It is supposed to help finding the paging structure that caused the fault (along with the error code pushed to the handler). What did you expected to see in `CR2`?

Comment: @MargaretBloom  mmu use the right pgd to access the pud page, and when the pud entry is not right, is there will be a new page fault?  To see the logs, i think it is, and the cr2 have new content. It is the pud value add the kernel base. My curious is that the mmu directly to access the physical addr, why the cr2 show the LA. In normal, the page table is right, so if the LA is not present, the cr2 will be the LA.   If the page table is not correct, why the cr2 is that?